# Why people don't switch to python 3?

Tags: python

Python 3 has been released more than 3 years ago. Until now, most of the framework and coursework i have seen always based on python 2.6 (or 2.7)

Even for Google App Engine, they also use python 2.

Are there any drawback of python 3 that prevents people from upgrading?

Comment: there's are a couple of drastic API changes...for which prevents the legacy codes to work...unless you do `2to3`

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why won't you switch to Python 3.x?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/766636/why-wont-you-switch-to-python-3-x)

Comment: Because there are some major changes between 2 and 3, like instead of `print "some line"` you have to use `print ("some line")`.

Comment: App Engine runs a modified version of Python. There is a fair amount of work for Google to upgrade it