# Take up Python 3.x or 2.x?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I started learning Python a few months back - and was immediately faced w/ this question. At that point I made the conscious decision to continue w/ 2.x [2.7.1 to be precise], because I was going to be involved in a project which was based on that version.

Over time I've come across numerous occurrences of lines like *"this feature will no longer be supported in 3.x"*, or, *"this will change"*, or something with a similar effect. I also came to appreciate the vast repository of toolkits/libraries which allowed me to program various components. However, quite a few of these toolkits/libraries carried a disclaimer that it only supports versions < 3.x [of course, most of them were also actively working on porting to ver 3.x]

At this point, when i can, at best, consider myself a greenhorn - should i continue w/ 2.7 or think of moving on to 3.x? After all, it's usually best as a programmer to be aware of the latest goings-on rather than getting left behind - even if it's a matter of a single version!

Comment: Relevant: http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3 Biggest problem is libraries not yet ported to 3.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Tutorial for Python - Should I use 2.x or 3.0?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/209888/tutorial-for-python-should-i-use-2-x-or-3-0)

Comment: Checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3483960/

Comment: If you're writing good code, you should find you don't use the "no longer supported in Python 3" features too often, anyway.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use `python 2.7` and start `python` with `-3` parameter so it'll warn you when you use stuff thats not in python3 (or will be deprecated there), more details about this warnings [here](http://docs.python.org/library/warnings.html#warnings.warnpy3k).

Comment: That'll give him *more* warnings. I think he's worried that he gets a lot already. :)

Comment: That'll make sure his code works in python3 _if_ he fixes those warnings :)

Answer (score 3):

It's a common question and you can find a great answer on the "official wiki" : http://wiki.python.org/moin/Python2orPython3

Answer (score 3):

Continue with 2.7. This question is asked here every few months. We'll notify the world when the answer changes. :-)

Answer (score 2):

When you have questions like this, it's often best to search first, read all the relevant answers, then compare all those answers to your needs.  If you still have an unmet need after reading all the previous answers, you have a good question.

The same is true for Python 3.1.  Search for all the libraries you need.  If there is some functionality you need that hasn't been ported to 3.1, you have an unmet need.   If you have an unmet need, then you can ask a unique and distinct question about that specific library that wasn't (yet) ported to 3.1.

This approach will always work and will never change.  Ever.

1. Search the built-in libraries for something you need.
2. Search PyPI for something you need.

If something you need is not available in 3.1, then, you have two choices.

1. Find someone with a similar package in Python 2 and find out what their conversion plan is.  Either use their beta in Python 3 or convert it yourself to Python 3.
2. Use Python 2 until they convert.  Or use Python 2 because you can't convert the missing library.

Note that the process starts with search.