# python 2.7 vs python 3.1

Tags: python, compatibility, versions

Some python 3 features and modules having been backported to  python 2.7 what are the notable differences between python 3.1 and python 2.7?

Comment: http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/index.html

Comment: Try using search, also.  For example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4570006/take-up-python-3-x-or-2-x, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/170921/to-learn-python-2-then-3-or-3-from-the-start

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think these resources might help you:

- A [introduction to Python "3000"](http://www.python.org/doc/essays/ppt/pycon2008/Py3kAndYou.pdf) from Guido van Rossum
- [Porting your code to Python 3](http://peadrop.com/slides/mp5.pdf)
- and of course the documentation of [changes in Python 3.0](http://docs.python.org/py3k/whatsnew/3.0.html)

And as you said

> Some python 3 features and modules having been backported to python 2.7

... I would invert that sentence and say [only few packages](https://python3wos.appspot.com/) yet have been ported from Python 2.x to 3.x. Great libraries like [PyGTK](http://pygtk.org/) still only work in Python 2. Migration can take a while in many projects so before you decide to use Python 3 you may rather think about writing your own projects in Python 2, while ensuring compatibility by testing with [2to3](http://docs.python.org/library/2to3.html) regularly.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use any of the python 3 function in python 2.7 then you can import **future** module at the beginning and then you can use it in your code.